How do materials scientists find and make candidate materials?
When searching for new materials that might exhibit interesting quantum effects such as superconductors or topological insulators, how do experimental physicists go about the process of making candidate materials? (Perhaps I should be using the word "manufacturing" rather than "making" - but that doesn't seem very appropriate to a lab setting.)
For example, is the usual process to start with in silico modelling and then proceed to make (how?) materials that look promising - or is it just a question of making what can be made (at random?) using the tools (which tools?) that currently exist?

Do you have a reference? "Quantum materials" is a publicity stunt it can mean anything and nothing at the same time.

See, for example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5592

A common method throughout physics for finding new things is to take something known and vary one aspect of it. With chemical compounds, there are many options.
For experimentalists who do materials synthesis / crystal growth, it is very common to take a known compound and substitute different elements in different places. This requires looking up ternary and higher phase diagrams to figure out how to grow them, but the idea is that substituting a rare-earth element with a magnetic moment in place of a nonmagnetic element can lead to magnetic effects, substituting a much larger element can create a sort of "chemical pressure," doping one compound with another with different valence alters the density of carriers (electrons / holes), and so on.
Occasionally new crystallographic structures are synthesized (like skutterudites or 1-1-5 compounds like CeCoIn$_5$) and people explore their various thermal, electronic, and structural properties, and find new compounds in the family.
One can also trade single crystals for polycrystalline samples, or try new preparation methods (flux growth, arc furnace, optical floating zone furnace, deposition, etc.).
Other times people do more complicated things like staggering layers of 2d materials to create heterostructures or twisted bilayer graphene and similar materials.
It is also common, especially in the context of semiconductor physics, to use ab initio simulations (namely, density functional theory) to predict new candidate materials.
And as quantum simulators progress, people can start to simulate synthetic quantum matter using qubits.
So overall, it's hardly random. At least, not on purpose. Sometimes the compounds you make surprise you with their properties, and this is probably how most "leaps" happen. Then people try variations on the new thing.
Hopefully this was helpful.
